# Count how many words in file test.txt start with “tol”?

Tags: bash

I'm new to Linux shell. I know there are tools to do this thing, such as awk. But I'm wondering if I could do it using grep or wc or other commands? awk seems intimidating to me. Thanks.

I tried grep and wc, like this:

```
grep tol test.txt | wc -w
```

But grep will give me the whole line.

If I tried the following:

```
grep '^tol$*' test.txt | wc -w
```

It only counts the line begins with mol.

How can I grep the words starting with tol?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. How far did you get and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I added some commands I have tried in the post. @thatotherguy

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
grep -o '\<tol[[:alpha:]]*\>' test.txt | wc -w
```

`<` - for beginning of the word,

`>` - the end of the word.

`[[:alpha:]]` - to avoid match of combinations like tol123 (You said you need only words).

`-o` - to show only matches, not the entire line.

Comment: Great answer. Could you explain a little bit more on [[:alpha:]]? Why do we need double square brackets? What is the meaning of the colon? What if I need to include the pattern toll123? Thanks.

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` - it's a POSIX character class (look here for reference: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html ). Equivalent to `[A-Za-z]`. For allowing numeric you can use `[[:alnum:]]` or `[A-Za-z0-9]`. POSIX character class needs quoting or double brackets. For allowing all but space, you can use `grep -o '\<tol[^[:space:]]*\>' f1 | wc -w`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same fairly simply with `awk`, e.g.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i~/^tol/ && n++} END {print n}'
```

**Example**

```
$ echo -e "tolerance topaz tolstoy\nbats toluene toledo" |
> awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i~/^tol/ && n++} END {print n}'
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to translate all whitespace characters into linefeeds so that each word starts on a new line, then `grep` can count them itself:

```
echo -e "tolerance topaz\ttolstoy\nbats toluene toledo" | tr '[:space:]' '\n' | grep -c "^tol"
4
```

Or, if using a file called `words.txt`:

```
tr '[:space:]' '\n' < words.txt | grep -c "^tol"
```